# How to make an array to output vertically in a table within a React Component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following array of data:

```
var arr = [ [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
  [ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ],
  [ 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ],
  [ 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ],
  [ 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 ]];
```

I can output the data into a horizontal view, but would like to create a vertical one instead.

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
  tablerows: function() {
    return this.props.arr.map(rows => {
        var row = rows.map(cell => <td>{cell}</td>); 
        return(
        <tr>{row}</tr>
        );
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return <table>{this.tablerows()}</table>;
  }
});
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/30476/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could transform the array and build a new one with take the value at swapped indices.

```js
var array = [ [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ], [ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ], [ 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ], [ 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ], [ 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 ]],
    result = array.reduce((r, a, i) =>
        (a.forEach((b, j) => (r[j] = r[j] || [])[i] = b), r), []);
    
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can transpose your "matrix" as follow

```html
let arr = this.props.arr;
let transArr = arr[0].map( (_, c)  => arr.map(r => r[c]));
return transArr.map(rows => { ... })
```

**Sample Code:**

```js
var arr = [ [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
  [ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ],
  [ 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ],
  [ 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ],
  [ 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 ],
  [ 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37 ],
  [ 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43 ],
  [ 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49 ],
  [ 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55 ],
  [ 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61 ],
  [ 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67 ],
  [ 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73 ],
  [ 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79 ],
  [ 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85 ],
  [ 86, 87, 88, 89, 90, 91 ],
  [ 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97 ],
  [ 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103 ],
  [ 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109 ] ];

var Hello = React.createClass({
  tablerows: function() {
    let arr = this.props.arr;
    let transArr = arr[0].map( (_, c)  => arr.map(r => r[c]));
   return transArr.map(rows => {
     var row = rows.map(cell => <td>{cell}</td>); 
     return(
       <tr>{row}</tr>
     );
   });
  },
  render: function() {
    return <table>{this.tablerows()}</table>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <Hello arr={arr} />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/85529/)

Comment: You can use stack snippet. Notice `<>` icon. Check `Babel` checkbox.

Comment: @Rajesh: Thank you. I am personally don't like that stack snippet, it is harder to indent while using Tab. Is it mandatory for short code block ?

Comment: Nope. Its just that readers can test your code. If you don't like, you can either collapse it or you can share links of other sites with your code. Its just a good to have thing. If you don't think my edit is not required, feel free to revert it

Comment: Good to know that, will try to remember next time :). And actually, your edit is very good for others to test the code, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like this:

#### Logic:

- Loop over `arr` and get the max length, so you know the max number of columns.
- Use this loop to create `rows`.
- Now create another loop, where you will create `td` and use index from parent loop to fetch item.

```js
var arr = [ [ 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 ],
  [ 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13 ],
  [ 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19 ],
  [ 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25 ],
  [ 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31 ]];
  
var Hello = React.createClass({
  tablerows: function() {
    const max = Math.max.apply(null, this.props.arr.map(x => x.length));
    return Array.from({length: max}, function(item, index){
      return <tr>
        {
          arr.map(x => <td>{x[index]}</td>)
        }
      </tr>
    })
  },
  render: function() {
    return <table>{this.tablerows()}</table>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(<Hello arr={arr}/>, document.querySelector('.content'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div class='content'></div>
```